# How to get values from the previous row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, intervals, postgresql-13

I have a table like this:

| ID | NUMBER | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 05/28/2020 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 05/29/2020 10:00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 05/31/2020 21:00:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 06/01/2020 21:00:00 |

And I want to show data like this:

| ID | NUMBER | TIMESTAMP | RANGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 05/28/2020 09:00:00 | 0 Days |
| 2 | 2 | 05/29/2020 10:00:00 | 0 Days |
| 3 | 1 | 05/31/2020 21:00:00 | 3,5 Days |
| 4 | 1 | 06/01/2020 21:00:00 | 1 Days |

So it takes 3,5 Days to process the number 1 process.

I tried:

```sql
select a.id, a.number, a.timestamp, ((a.timestamp-b.timestamp)/24) as days 
from my_table a
left join (select number,timestamp from my_table) b 
on a.number=b.number
```

Didn't work as expected. How to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [window function **`lag()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

With standard interval output:

```sql
SELECT *, timestamp - lag(timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY id)
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id;
```

If you need decimal number like in your example:

```sql
SELECT *, round((extract(epoch FROM timestamp - lag(timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY id)) / 86400)::numeric, 2) || ' days'
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id;
```

If you also need to display '0 days' instead of NULL like in your example:

```sql
SELECT *,  COALESCE(round((extract(epoch FROM timestamp - lag(timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY id)) / 86400)::numeric, 2), 0) || ' days'
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ec10b29b7f8c0064198beba40d0cc2cb)*